# JVM Timezone set to GMT. I need system timezone where the System timezone is, say, IST

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, jvm

I have set the jvm timezone using the -D parameters. Is there a way to programmatically get the System timezone? I do not intend to modify the JVM timezone set. I just need to use the local system's timezone.

Comment: If you set the -D param, your default ts is set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a private method `TimeZone.getSystemTimeZoneID`, which is not in Java standards.
You may call it via Reflection:

```
Method m = TimeZone.class.getDeclaredMethod("getSystemTimeZoneID", String.class, String.class);
m.setAccessible(true);

String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
String systemTimeZone = (String) m.invoke(null, javaHome, null);
```

There is a similar private method `TimeZone.getSystemGMTOffsetID`. It returns a string like `GMT+08:00`.